# Qt5: how to determine screen pixel format?

Tags: qt4, qt5, embedded-linux

I'm porting an application from Embedded Qt4 to Qt5. Therefore, I need an equivalent for the following expression:

```
QScreen::instance()->pixelFormat()
```

QScreen does not have the static `instance()` function anymore, nor does it provide `pixelFormat()`.

So basically I need to determine the pixel format of the screen. I need it as second argument for the constructor of `QImage`.

Comment: Maybe by using a tiny bit of private API (QPA, `QPlatformScreen`): `QScreen::handle()` then `screenFormat()`. You need `QT += gui-private`. By the way, you get the list of the screens via `QGuiApplication` (`primaryScreen()` and `screen()`).

Answer (score 0):

If the following workaround doesn't meet your needs, use:
`QPlatformScreen * QScreen::handle() const`.

**Workaround:**
Maybe you could use `QScreen::depth` and then match its value with the proper `QImage::format`:

```
QImage::Format ConvertDepthToFormat(int depth)
{
   QImage::Format format = QImage::Format_Invalid;
   switch (depth)
   {
      case 16:
         format = QImage::Format_RGB16;
         break;

      case 32:
         format = QImage::Format_RGB32;
         break; 
   }
   return format;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);

    int depth = 0;
    foreach (QScreen *screen, QGuiApplication::screens())
    {
       depth = screen->depth();
       qDebug() << "Depth:" << depth << "-bits";
       QImage::Format format = ConvertDepthToFormat(depth);
    }
    return a.exec(); 
}
```